# Ning: Connect to websocket and wait for response

Tags: java, websocket, asynchttpclient

Using Ning to create and connect to Websocket, following is my configuration ,

```
 NettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig config = new NettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig();
 config.addProperty(NettyAsyncHttpProviderConfig.USE_BLOCKING_IO, "true");

 AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder builder = new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
                .setAsyncHttpClientProviderConfig(config);

 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(
                new NettyAsyncHttpProvider(builder.build()));

 AsyncHttpClient.BoundRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareGet(createUri(method))
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, "Upgrade")
                .addHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.UPGRADE, "WebSocket");

 websocket = requestBuilder.execute(new WebSocketUpgradeHandler.Builder()
                .addWebSocketListener(this).build()).get();
```

using websocket to send text message,

```
 if (websocket!=null && websocket.isOpen())
       websocket.sendTextMessage(jObj.toString());// send
```

`onMessage()` method of the listener will add the response to a list

```
@Override
public void onMessage(String message) {
   serverResponse.add(message);
}
```

After sending the text message, I have method which formats the response and save the result

`result = responseFromServer();`

```
private String responseFromServer() {
    String response = null;
    sleep(100);
   if(!serverResponse.isEmpty())
      //format the message which is added in list
    return response;
}
```

issue is, if I dont have 'sleep(100)' in the above method, for request1- response is null and for request2, I get response1. I would like the websocket to work as synchronous so that, once I send the message, it should wait unitll the response is received and go forward! ANy suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `wait` and `notify` on a object,

```
synchronized (someObject){
  try {
     someObject.wait();
     result = responseFromServer();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //when the object is interrupted
   }
}
```

and in `onMessage` notify the object once you got the message,

```
@Override
public void onMessage(String message) {
     serverResponse.add(message);
     synchronized(someObject) {
          someObject.notify();
     }
}
```

Comment: @sssV can you clarify what "someobject" is in this case ?

Comment: Has anyone an answer to why this happens ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the CountDownLatch concept as illustrated in the link below:

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class WordgameClientEndpoint {

    private static CountDownLatch latch;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        // same as above
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message, Session session) {
        // same as above
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        logger.info(String.format("Session %s close because of %s", session.getId(), closeReason));
        latch.countDown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
        try {
            client.connectToServer(WordgameClientEndpoint.class, new URI("ws://localhost:8025/websockets/game"));
            latch.await();

        } catch (DeploymentException | URISyntaxException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api/